# How can i remover google default marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an app where i am displaying list of taxis around using a custom maker, but my default marker still appears over the custom marker, how do i remove the default marker. I tried research on this, but nothing came

Here is my code where i added the customer marker:

```
for (DriverInfo driverInfo: result.getDriverInfos()) {

                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).bottom_view_on_successful_pick_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(new LatLng((Double.parseDouble(driverInfo.getfLat())), Double.parseDouble(driverInfo.getfLong())));
                    markerOptions.title(driverInfo.getvFirst() +" "+ driverInfo.getvLast());
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pullova_option_ride_map_pin));

                    Marker carMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                    carMarker.setTag(0);

                    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(carMarker.getPosition()));

                    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(carMarker.getPosition(),2));

                    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).driverMakers.put(carMarker, driverInfo);

                }
```

and this is the end result visually :

[image]

Comment: `marker.remove()` or `mGoogleMap.clear()`

Comment: well why are you adding two markers? The first one you add is the car image like you want but then you call `mGoogleMap.addMarker` again which just a position which adds the default marker

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line:

```
mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(carMarker.getPosition()));
```